# Export LocatorPane as image by button

Tags: dynamic, export, locator

How to Export LocatorPane as image by button or at least by something else?

Kuba, thank you! Your method works in a simple case:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {{1, 1}/2, {-1, 1}/2, {1, -1}/2}}, {Dynamic@LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}],
Appearance -> Graphics[{Red , Disk[Scaled[{.5, .5}], .2], Inset["a", Scaled[{.1, .1} + 0.5]]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}]]}]

Button["Export", Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "expimg.png"}], Rasterize@ToExpression@First@NotebookRead@Experimental`PreviousCell[]]]
```

But in my case need to fix something. This code results an image with initial positions of locators:

```
hkl = {-1, 2, 3};

Manipulate[Pane[
  DynamicModule[{pt = {{1000, 1059}/2, {1000, 1059}/2.2}},
   Column[
    {Dynamic@
      LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
       Image[Import[
         "http://download.hdd.tomsk.ru/preview/warpaheh.jpg"], 
        ImageSize -> Zoom],


       Appearance -> {
         Graphics[{Red, 
           Disk[Scaled[{1000, 1059}/(2*{1000, 1059})], 
            Dynamic[PointRadius]]}, 
          PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {0, 1059}}, 
          ImageSize -> Dynamic[Zoom]],
         Dynamic[
          Style[Row[hkl], RGBColor[TextColor, TextColor, TextColor], 
           Zoom*PointRadius/100]]
         }]

     }]]
  , ImageSize -> {1000, 1000}, Scrollbars -> True, 
  ScrollPosition -> {150, 200}],
 Row[{
   Column[{
     Row[{Control[{{TextColor, 0.5}, 0, 
          1}] Control[{{TextColor, 0.5, ""}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}, 
          InputField[#, FieldSize -> {4, 1}] &}]}], 
     Row[{Control[{{Zoom, 1000}, 100, 3000, 
          100}] Control[{{Zoom, 1000, ""}, {100, 100}, {3000, 3000}, 
          InputField[#, FieldSize -> {4, 1}] &}]}], 
     Row[{Control[{{PointRadius, 3}, 1, 
          20}] Control[{{PointRadius, 3, ""}, {1, 1}, {20, 20}, 
          InputField[#, FieldSize -> {4, 1}] &}]}],
     }, Right]
   }, Spacer[50]]
 ]
Button["Export", 
 Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "expimg.png"}], 
  Rasterize@
   ToExpression@First@NotebookRead@Experimental`PreviousCell[]]]
```

How to implement the export of this picture?

How to export an image with modified locators?

Please, look at my code. Why it still doesn't work?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_R6abD1r7RXU0NrZS1GdGF3U1E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, do you want the whole Manipulate to be exported or only the graphics part? Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Kuba, you're a genius!!! This is exactly what I need! Thank you so much!

Comment: All credits to Mathematica.SE community since most things I've learned here :)

Comment: Please, take a [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 3):

I have reformulated your code a little bit. If you want to make complicated GUIs I think it is better to leave `Manipulate` and do all that with `DynamicModule`, `Sliders` etc.

The point about exporting. Thanks to the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15707704#15707704) with [Rojo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/109/rojo), it seems that the most reliable way to export the state of something that `Dynamic[vars]` are involved is to put the `Button` in the same scope as `vars` are. So here I'm putting it inside `DynamicModule` but you can easily make `pt` `` Global` `` variable.

I was not sure what do you want to export at the end so this is only a graphical part of the code, easy to change.

Old solutions are in edit history. They work but only for simple examples, and only because of side effects.

```
DynamicModule[{controls, pt, TextColor, Zoom, PointRadius, locatorpane, loc, hkl},
 Dynamic[Refresh[
   Column[{
     controls,         
     Pane[Dynamic[loc = locatorpane ], ImageSize -> {500, 500}, Scrollbars -> True,
                                        ScrollPosition -> {150, 200}]         
     }, Left],
   None]],

 Initialization :> (
   pt = {{1000, 1059}/2, {1000, 1059}/2.2};
   TextColor = .5;
   Zoom = 500;
   PointRadius = 3;
   hkl = {-1, 2, 3};

   controls = Grid[{
      {"TextColor", Slider[Dynamic@TextColor, {0, 1}], InputField[Dynamic@TextColor, FieldSize -> {4, 1}]},
      {"Zoom", Slider[Dynamic@Zoom, {100, 3000, 100}], InputField[Dynamic@Zoom, FieldSize -> {4, 1}]},
      {"PointRadius", Slider[Dynamic@PointRadius, {1, 20}], InputField[Dynamic@PointRadius, FieldSize -> {4, 1}]},
      {Button["Export", Print[Rasterize@loc]], ""}
      }];

   locatorpane = LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],         
     Image[Import["http://download.hdd.tomsk.ru/preview/warpaheh.jpg"], 
           ImageSize -> Dynamic@Zoom], 
     Appearance -> {Graphics[{Red, Dynamic@AbsolutePointSize@PointRadius,
                              Point[{0, 0}]}],           
                    Dynamic[Style[Row[hkl], RGBColor[TextColor, TextColor, TextColor], 
                                 Zoom*PointRadius/100]]}];           
   )]
```

[image]